# Erro IONIC dependecias não econtradas

Tags: android, ionic, gradle

Olá estou com erro no IONIC ao usar comandos para compilar para android.
Apareçe esse erro toda vez que tento um desses comandos no

`ionic run android --target meuDispositivo`

`ionic build android`

Sempre aparece a seguinte mensagem abaixo, se alguém souber como consertar  esses erros de dependências eu agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já tentou remover a plataforma e adicionar novamente :
`ionic platform rm android` e `ionic platform add android`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução para este problema estava no Android SDK Manager faltava instalar 
o `Android Support Repository` depois de instalado ao usar o comando `ionic build android` ou o comando `ionic android run --target meuDispositivo` não apresentaram problemas na execução e compilaram normalmente.

[image: Solução para erro no ionic]